# How do I call a function to add/remove dots and dashes on a given cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here in Brazil we use a 20 number string to identify judicial cases, in a standardized manner, separated by a dots and dashes.

The problem is in most systems we use, when you export to excel it takes away the dots and dashes, thus creating a problem when exporting that data to a system that actually needs the dots and dashes to work (some poorly coded excuse for a legal system).

What I'm trying to do is use VBA to call a function that fixes the number so I can export it.

The way the standardized number works is like this:

> 0010159-24.2015.8.10.0001
>   (CaseNumber-VerifyingDigit.Year.Court.State.City)

When I export my current data do Excel, it shows like this:

> 00101592420158100001

And I need it to go back to the format above!

I'm 100% stuck though, would love some input.

Edit:

To clarify some stuff.

The string is always 20 numbers long, its a standardized number set by our National Council of Justice, it never changes. All the cases follow that 20 number string format.

The cell with the number is always in text, so it doesn't show as scientific notation.

Comment: What format is the cell containing the number? What file format are you exporting this to? What does your code look like? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57680458/edit) to clarify things

Comment: `format(left(Range("A1"),9),"0000000\-00\.") & format(Mid(Range("A1"),10),"0000\.0\.00\.0000")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want to change the values in a range so that they are in the needed format (with dots and dashes) so then you can export it somewhere else?

Maybe something like that can help? I assume you have your 00101592420158100001 in a cell A1.

```
Sub x()
Range("A1").Value = Format(Range("A1"), "#######-##.####.#.##.####")
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1:** As the number in cell A1 starts with 00 I assumed that you have cell A1 formatted as text. So that the macro proposed by me will only add a certain dashes or dots.

**EDIT 2:** Why the code above was not working is the fact that in VBA the "@" character represents a displayed character, and "#" works for numbers.
So, as suggested in a comment below, the subroutine like this:

```
Sub x()
Range("A1").Value = Format(Range("A1"), "@@@@@@@-@@.@@@@.@.@@.@@@@")
End Sub
```

will do the trick.

But as you want to choose a range to be formatted I would suggest using something more like that:

```
Sub forhenriquef()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Choose the range, OK?", "Macro for henriquef", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     For Each cell In rng
          cell.Value = Format(cell, "@@@@@@@-@@.@@@@.@.@@.@@@@")
     Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: So do you first format a cell to text and then copy the 20-digit number into that cell? I observed that when I first paste the value and then format it, the excel tends to change the values (if there were zeros at the beginning - they are gone, and the last two digits change to zeros), which we do not want. Make sure the number in a cell has 20 digits and then try this: `Range("A1").Value = Format(Range("A1"), "@@@@@@@-@@.@@@@.@.@@.@@@@")` instead.

Comment: @henriquef, so did it work for you? Tried it today and it works fine on my computer.

Comment: hey, it worked! But unless I'm mistaken now I'd have to edit the sub for every single cell id like to adjust, right? Or can we adapt the code to work on the selected cell.

Comment: @henriquef, just look at my edited post, that should give you an idea of how to adapt the code to work on a selected cells :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't VBA but we can make one, however if you're just looking to reformat the text and it is as you show with no variation (I sense a date is in there and the length of this string may vary), this should work for you.

Assuming you data starts in cell A1, you can put this formula in row 1 somewhere and get the desired format.

`=LEFT(A1,7)&"-"&RIGHT(LEFT(A1,9),2)&"."&RIGHT(LEFT(A1,13),4)&"."&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,7),1)&"."&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),2)&"."&RIGHT(A1,4)`

Or as Scott had mentioned you can use the shorter:

`=TEXT(LEFT(A1,9),"0000000\-00\.")&TEXT(MID(A1,10,20),"0000\.0\.00\.0000")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you just extend the format to do this all in one `TEXT` formula?

Comment: No, Excel will only use 15 significant digits, the end will be lost.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the info, @ScottCraner I don't deal with text formulas too often.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the tips. Both functions returned partial results tho. Longest string returned this: 0055136-#.#.#.#.#. Scotts short one returned this: 0018459-82.

Comment: @HenriqueFontanadeOliveira You specifically mentioned that the string size is 20...

Comment: Yes the original string before adding the one dash and 4 dots. I think I didn't make myself very clear and I'm sorry for that, English is a second language and sometimes I screw up. So the final string would be 25 digits long, like the example I used in my original post.